Sink backup 14 story condo
I live in a 14 story condo building. My kitchen sink has been backing up when I am not using it. It smells like dishwasher detergent and it’s bubbly. Our building plumber ran the main line and said there a grease blockage. Within a week the issue is still here. Any suggestions? I thought about installing a back flow I the drain line.
Thanks
Jim

Sounds like it's time to get the plumber back and do more work to completely clear the grease blockage, and not just open it up slightly.  There could also have been a second restriction that didn't get completely cleared the first time.  Often times a grease blockage needs more than just a snake to clean out, and especially in a commercial condo, may need a commercial plumber familiar with tall buildings and the equipment to clean out the longer drain lines.
